# How to launch schdule task when a iPhone is plugged or unplugged from the system in windows xp

Tags: c#, ios, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

Can any one let me know how can we capture the events for iPhone when it is connected/disconnected to a Windows XP system? Based on the connected and disconnected events I want to launch different programs.

All the search results I found were related to USB mass storage/ removable disks. But when iPhone is plugged in Windows XP, it gets listed under scanner and camera devices and it wont have any drive letter associated with it. I would like the solution in any scripting language or C is fine.

Comment: Windows XP [is no longer supported](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle). If you got really urgent a case, migrate to more modern an OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI. I have only Windows 7. But this work for me.

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_USBControllerDevice | ForEach-Object {[WMI]($_.Dependent)}).Description | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_ -eq "Apple iPhone"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Task scheduler` to do this created task set a trigger that `On an event` (The event being a connect of the iphone you should be able to find the event name and tag in the logs) it starts the program you want then add another trigger for the disconnect event.